# multiple "main" target within an esp-idf project

Tags: esp-idf

I am developing code for an ESP32 chip, using ESP-IDF.

I would like to set up an ESP-IDF project in which there is more than one "main" target that I can build, because I have a few different pieces of software that run on different devices, but which all rely on the same underlying components. Is something like this possible using esp-idf?

I considered just creating multiple separate projects with `idf.py create-project`, but each piece of software shares a lot of the same components, and having multiple different projects makes it difficult to share components.

I also considered just writing a single main target with #ifdefs for switching between the different bits of software that I'm trying to build, but it gets really messy that way.